# In Easel.js SpriteSheetBuilder using bitmaps

Tags: createjs

I am trying to use the SpriteSheetBuilder class to generate a sprite sheet on the fly. Currently, I have just been tinkering with some example code found on github. https://github.com/CreateJS/EaselJS/blob/master/examples/SpriteSheetBuilder.html

In the example they are generating frames from vector objects. I need to generate frames that also include images. The documentation says to pass in a display object when calling builder.addFrame() but doesn't specify if images are valid or invalid.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

The documentation says any `DisplayObject` can be used. You can not pass an image, but you can use an EaselJS Bitmap instance. Make sure that it is loaded before calling `addFrame`, or it will add nothing to the SpriteSheet.

http://www.createjs.com/docs/easeljs/classes/SpriteSheetBuilder.html#method_addFrame

Comment: Thanks for helping out! For some reason, I was not able to get it to work by passing in an Easel.js Bitmap instance. I am convinced that ought to work, though. What did end up working for me was creating a new Container instance and drawing the Bitmap instance into that. I then passed the whole Container to addFrame and it was added to the SpriteSheet, no problem.

Comment: That is odd, since all a container does is transform the stage contents, and draw its children. Should not have that behaviour.